# TeamViewer, force people who connect to use presentation

Tags: presentations

I'm using TeamViewer for presentation issues.

I want be let people see my dekstop, but can't click it or control it, and remove that annoying blue mouse cursor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preferences, you can set what control the other end has over your computer.  One setting is Presentation → "Allow partner to interact", and another is Security → "Access control incoming".  I'm running the Mac version, but I imagine the Windows version is similar.